# How to get JSON collections using Bookshelf

Tags: node.js, bookshelf.js

I am using Bookshelf, and I want to do something like this:

```
function myfunc() {
    this.vals = Accounts.forge().fetch();
}
```

I can get the collection object, but I can't call .toJSON on it to store in this.vals.  What am I missing?  I can access the collection in a .then() promise:

```
.then(function(collection) {
    console.log(collection.toJSON());
})
```

How can I store this JSON in this.vals?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, the `fetch()` call returns a promise that is fulfilled via `then()`. The promise object itself has no `toJSON()` method. You'd need something like this:

```
function myfunc() {
    this.vals = Accounts.forge().fetch()
        .then(function(accounts) {
            return accounts.toJSON();
        });
}
```